# Spring Integration - Parallel ordered processing

Tags: spring-integration

In the application i work on, there is a continuous flow of messages coming from a TCP socket. Messages have different types. Different types of messages should be processed in parallel. But each specific type of message must be processed in the order they come in.
I used ExecutorChannel from spring integration and it solves parallel processing need. I created a channel for each specific type of message.
But i cannot guarantee ordered processing of messages for specific types.

Is there a way to do ordered processing with publish/subscribe channels while also using parallel processing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use the same `ExecutorChannel` but as an input for each type. The trick that each of them should be configured with executors with a single thread. So, you have as much single-threaded executor channels as you have message types.

Another trick is like `QueueChannel` for each type and polling endpoints with the `fixed-delay` as subscribers to those queues.

One more option available since the current Spring Integration 5.0 is `FluxMessageChannel`. The ordering is guaranteed by the internal Reactor's `Flux` and the parallelism will be achieved by the subscribers - the processing messages in `Flux` is happened in the subscriber thread.

Comment: As ExecutorChannel accepts an Executor as constructor parameter, how can i force it to always work with the same thread for each different message type? Shall i assign thread pool executors whose maxpoolsize is 1?

Comment: Well, again: you have to have as much single- threaded ExecutorChannels as much message types you have. Since one executor Channel for messages routed to it by type is based on a single-threaded executor, that guarantees a proper order for them

Comment: Also see one more possible option in my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan could you provide a simple example to show how to control threading while using `Flux` + `FluxMessageChannel`? What I did was passing a `Flux` into `.split()` followed by a `FluxMessageChannel`. When I add `.log()` to the `Flux` I can see that back pressure is handled correctly, as consequent `onNext()` request are sent only when the data is processed, but the handling is performed only on one thread. I tried adding `subscribeOn()` to the `Flux`, using `ExecutorChannel`, or even a `Poller` with an `Executor` set, but couldn't make the handling to be run in parallel.

Comment: M-m-m. Sounds like a separate SO question, Mikhail ?

Comment: Sure :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496099/spring-integration-5-0-project-reactor-controlling-threads