# Spring Integration 5.0 + Project Reactor: controlling threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Followup question for https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136941/1776585

I can't make my integration handler to run in parallel threads while using `Flux` + `split()` + `FluxMessageChannel`.

Consider the following snippet:

```
// ...
.handle(message -> Flux.range(0, 10)
    .doOnNext(i -> LOG.info("> " + i))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
.split()
.channel(new FluxMessageChannel())
.handle(message -> LOG.info(" -> " + message.getPayload())))
// ...
```

All logs are output in one thread:

```
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 0
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 0
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 1
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 1
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 2
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 2
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 3
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 3
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 4
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 4
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 5
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 5
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 6
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 6
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 7
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 7
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 8
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 8
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : > 9
[     parallel-1] d.a.Application    :  -> 9
```

How can I force the processing in multiple threads?

I've tried using `.parallel().runOn()` on the `Flux`, but that just makes fetching data parallel, but actual handling still runs on one thread.

I've also tried `.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())` on the `Flux` with no effect.

And also adding `ExecutorChannel` or a `Poller` with an executor to a handler didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does some trick:

```
.channel(new FluxMessageChannel())
.channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
.handle(message -> LOG.info(" -> " + message.getPayload())))
```

And those messages consumed by the `FluxMessageChannel` is going to be paralled by that additional `ExecutorChannel`.

I think what you are asking is like a feature request to make the mentioned `FluxMessageChannel` configurable. And such a `subscribeOn/publishOn` etc. could be configured there.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter!

Comment: I feel a bit ashamed of myself, cause I definitely remember trying this and came to the conclusion it didn't work; but now I tried again, and it does. Thanks :)